# How to automatically update a content of table after an insert update or delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a table from a junction between 3 tables.

The issue that I'm facing is that this table becomes outdated once a new modification affects once of the original table used to supply its data.

How should solve this problem? Is a trigger the only solution?

Comment: Create a view. Will always have up-to-date data!

Comment: Why do you create a table from other tables? Is there some reason it can't just be a view? What content do the 3 source and 1 other tables have? A bit more info could lead to far better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

- Live with the outdated data and periodically (say once a day or once an hour) update the table.
- Use a trigger to update the associated values.
- Use a view.
- Use an *indexed view* if possible (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15)).

The last option is a way to define a view that SQL Server updates *automatically* -- what is called a *materialized view* in other databases.  That said, not all queries are supported in materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

"*There are two problems in computer science.  Cache coherency, and naming things.*"  Tables derived from other tables exemplify both.

SQL Server supports materialized views, if you actually need them.  Before you decide you do, do what every good carpenter does: measure twice and cut once.  That is, write an ordinary view, and see how fast it is. If it's too slow -- however defined -- find out why.  Most of the time, slow views can be sped up using indexes.  If you have 100s of millions of rows, you might convert the view to a function that takes an argument applied to the WHERE clause, making it a "parameterized" view.